# Spring Boot OAuth2 linking internal users with Facebook/Google login

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, google-oauth, spring-social, spring-oauth2

I have implemented a Spring Boot application with AngularJS frontend. Have also setup users along with their permissions. Right now I am able to login with any of these users and is working well with Spring security. I would like to turn this traditional login flow into a Facebook/Google OAuth login flow, where in I want the users to use their Facebook/Google account to log in and they will be mapped to their internal users automatically. This will help me in getting rid of maintaining passwords of these users.

I found many articles talking about setting up OAuth with Spring Boot and how can Facebook/Google login be integrated with a Spring Boot application. But I am having difficulty in finding an article which talks about linking a Facebook/Google user with internal users.

How should I go about this?

Comment: check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967162/auto-merge-facebook-and-internal-users

Answer (score 1):

1. Look for a user with the associated facebook/google userID.
2. If that user does not exist you request an email address and try to match it with an existing legacy account.
3. If you do not get a email adress for any reason (not acceping the authorization request for example) you could show a popup box asking for the email adress explaining why you need it.
4. You then locate the legacy user and merge it adding the facebook/google ID to look it up in the future.
5. If no user is found with the email adress you either refuse the user or create a new account.

you should be able to do all of this by implementing your own `AuthenticationProvider`

Answer (score 0):

Before you can fetch a user’s data from Facebook, you must specify your application’s ID and secret by setting the `spring.social.facebook.appId` and `spring.social.facebook.appSecret` properties. You can set these via any means supported by Spring Boot, including setting them in an `application.properties` file:

```
spring.social.facebook.appId=233668646673605
spring.social.facebook.appSecret=33b17e044ee6a4fa383f46ec6e28ea1d
```

For reference you can follow this article: https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-facebook/